# How to remove extra information from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map api in my website. I need to remove extra details (landmarks, businesses..etc) from google map. I am doing this by using below parameters while initializing map.

styles: [
    {
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'transit',
        stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]
    }
]

However, still there is some details which i need to remove but not able to do that. Please check below screen shot of map. I have marked places which i want to remove.

[image: Google Map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Maybe try hiding landscape features, using the same syntax you used to hide POI features:

```
{ featureType: 'landscape.natural', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] }
```